# using python selenium in web scraping, want to print a web table data on to console using for loop

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, html-table

Please help me with the below code. I want to print it in table format with total rows = 35, columns = 6.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
#import urllib.request
from tabulate import tabulate
from selenium import webdriver   # for webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options  # for suppressing the browser

class States():
    def __init__(self):
        url = "https://www.mohfw.gov.in/"
        # self.res = requests.get(url)
        # self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.res.text, 'lxml')
        self.op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.op.add_argument('headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\web drivers\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe", options= self.op)
        self.driver.get(url)
        self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("open-table").click()

    def get_data(self):
        print("S.No"     "Name of State / UT"     "Active Cases*"     "Cured/Discharged/Migrated*"     "Deaths**"     "Total Confirmed cases*")
        self.base_table = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("table")
        table_row = 35
        table_cols = 6

        for i in range(1, table_row +1):
            for j in range(1, table_cols +1):
                print(self.base_table.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='state-data']/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[" +str(i)+"]/td[" + str(j) + "]").text)


state=States()
state.get_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the url for better understanding? If you are particularly looking to scrape a table data from web, the best way to look use BeautifulSoup. identify the class name and you can simply loop through the row and individual data. have a look at the following snippet

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.imdb.com/india/top-rated-indian-movies/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=8a7876cd-2844-4017-846a-2c0876945b7b&pf_rd_r=JYVEVKT1J5S5HQZEVYN1&pf_rd_s=right-5&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=boxoffice&ref_=chtbo_india_tr_rhs_1"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

movie_rating = []
movie_name = []

#identifying the table using class name
imdb_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'chart full-width')

for imdb in imdb_table.find_all('tbody'):
    #find all rows together
    rows = imdb.find_all('tr')
    #simply loop through individual element
    for row in rows:
        name = row.find('td', class_ = 'titleColumn').text
        movie_name.append(re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', ' ',name))
        rating = row.find('td', class_ = 'ratingColumn imdbRating').text
        movie_rating.append(float(rating))
```

Comment: #Code Updated

Soubhik, i tried to use BeautifulSoup but i wanted a click action which i wasn't able to get from BS, so i used selenium instead.
url = https://www.mohfw.gov.in/